# Set-Builder notation for flattening a nested set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume we have a set of sets $\textbf{P}=\{ \textbf{P}_j \}_{j=1}^{n}$ where $\textbf{P}_j=\{P_j^i \}_{i=1}^{m_j}$ for every $\textbf{P}_j \in \textbf{P}$. Now, we want to build a set of $P_j^i$ for every $(i,j) \in j \times m_j$ for every $j\in n$ from $\textbf{P}$. In plain words, we are flattening an unaligned nested set, or an unaligned matrix.

Here is expression [1]: 
$$\{p\in\textbf{P}_j|\textbf{P}_j \in \textbf{P} \} $$ 
where the condition is actually on the member's domain.

And another expression [2]:
$$\bigcup_{j=1}^n \{ p|p \in \textbf{P}_j \}, where\ \textbf{P}_j \in \textbf{P}$$

Which expression makes more sense and why? Are there any other expressions for this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notationally simplest way to describe the desired set is as
$$
\bigcup \textbf{P}.
$$
The only downside is that some mathematicians, in my experience, aren't very comfortable with the general set theoretic union and prefer to union sets over a given index set.

If you want to take that route, notice that
$$
\bigcup_{j=1}^n \{ p \mid p \in \textbf{P}_j \} = \bigcup_{j=1}^n \textbf{P}_j,
$$
so you can simplify your 2nd expression.

Finally, your first expression strikes me as rather inelegant and borderline confusing. You could rewrite it as
$$
 \{p \mid \exists x \in \textbf{P} \colon p \in x \}
$$
but that's really just an overly complicated way to write $\bigcup \textbf{P}$.

Comment: Thank you for your speedy answer. The simplification of expression [2] is elegant enough in my book.

Comment: @Irokin You're very welcome!